# Android/Monodroid ApplyTransformation Not Called

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android

I am using a custom animation to expand and contract my view, found on another answer here on SO.  My problem is, ApplyTransformation never gets called therefore, nothing happens.

Is there anything else I'm supposed to be doing?

```
private void BrandTextClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Animation animation = null;
    if (expanded) {
        animation = new ExpandAnimation (listView, 0, height);
    } else {
        animation = new ExpandAnimation(listView, height, 0);
    }
    animation.Duration = 500;
    animation.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(1);
    listView.Animation = animation;
    animation.StartNow ();
    listView.Invalidate ();

    expanded = !expanded;
}
```

...

```
public class ExpandAnimation : Animation {
    private int mStartHeight;
    private int mDeltaHeight;
    private View mContent;

    public ExpandAnimation(View content, int startHeight, int endHeight) : base() {
        mContent = content;
        mStartHeight = startHeight;
        mDeltaHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
    }

    public override void Initialize (int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight)
    {
        base.Initialize (width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    protected override void ApplyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.LayoutParameters;
        lp.Height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight *
                           interpolatedTime);
        mContent.LayoutParameters = lp;
        mContent.RequestLayout();
    }

    public override bool WillChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Android.Animation package/namespace and ValueAnimation like so:

```
    ValueAnimator animator = null;
    if (expanded) {
        handle.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ArrowDownFloat);
        animator = ValueAnimator.OfObject (new HeightEvaluator (listView), height, 0);
    } else {
        handle.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ArrowUpFloat);
        animator = ValueAnimator.OfObject (new HeightEvaluator (listView), 0, height);
    }

    animator.SetDuration(500);
    animator.SetInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator (1));
    animator.Start ();

    expanded = !expanded;
```